# What would represent here

Tags: word-usage

Amar had come as she had hoped. But when she was shocked at the sight of him she realized she never actually believed he **would**. Three years had passed with no news from him. On the day she told her parents she would invite him she had not allowed herself to pray,

Comment: Please see "[Details, please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"would" represent "would come" here.

It means that "Though she hoped Amar to come, but she thought the possibility is very low."